# All arguments are evaluated before the function is called

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

```py
def new_if(pred, then_clause, else_clause):
    if pred:
        then_clause
    else:
        else_clause
def p(x):
    if x>20:
        print(x)
    else:
        new_if(x>5, print(x), p(2*x))
p(4)
```

This function will output: 4 8 16 32. Why does this happen when even when the if statement in (x>20) is False.

Comment: The title of your question is the answer to it - your code evaluates `print(x) and p(2*x)` before your `new_if` function is called. By the way, `if pred: then_clause else: else_clause` does literally nothing.

Comment: When you first plug in `p(4)` since 4<20, the `else` within the `p` function is evaluated. Thus the `new_if` function is called with parameters `4>5, print(4), p(8)`. Now  since 4<5, it does the else clause which is `p(8)`. In `p(8)` , `8` is less than 20. Thus the procedure is repeated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I would like to understand the logic of this code in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774110/i-would-like-to-understand-the-logic-of-this-code-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, all arguments are evaluated before the function is called, otherwise the function cannot know what is passed to it. So what you are doing is actually:

1. call `p(4)`
2. 4 < 20, call `new_if(4>5, print(4), p(2*4))` in else statement
3. evaluate argument, call `print(4)` and `p(8)`
4. 8 < 20, call `new_if(8>5, print(8), p(2*8))` in else statement
5. evaluate argument, call `print(8)` and `p(16)`
6. 16 < 20, call `new_if(16>5, print(16), p(2*16))` in else statement
7. evaluate argument, call `print(16)` and `p(32)`
8. 32 > 20, call `print(32)` in if statement

As `print()` and `p()` return `None`, all `new_if(pred, None, None)` is doing nothing:

```
if pred:
    None
else:
    None
```