# why does "int" come before "input"? I would like to understand the logic of this code

Tags: python, syntax, operator-precedence

My teacher gave me this question: make a program that reads an integer and prints it.
So I found this code:

```py
integer_number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

print("You entered:", integer_number)
```

I would like to understand why the function: "int" comes first than "input"

I expected the "input" function to be first than the "int" function since "input" has the function of requesting information from the user so that he can fill it in and the "int" converts a given string to an integer.

Comment: I can easily see that you don't understand what is going on (maybe you need a new teacher), but you have managed to explain exactly what your thought processes are that result in your expectations. +1

Comment: @pippo1980 the negative comment you presumably replied to here must've been deleted as it looks like you're replying to a comment that's positive.

Comment: @Z3RO in any programming language, nested actions (including function calls) like `a(b())` are always evaluated inside-to-outside (`b()` then `a()`), not left-to-right (`a()` then `b()`). It's like in math if you see `3(2+4)` - you do the `2+4` first and THEN multiply the result by `3`.

Comment: @EdMortond dont know if it was about a comment , maybe was just the -3 they gave to the OP. To me his question seemed legitimate. I know its probably trivial to someboidy into any kind of programming but took me a lot to find any reference into documentation to state the obvious. what's the point of saying : ... XXX is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering....  ??
Just my two cents

Comment: @pippo1980: I guessed as much. I voted +1 (it looks like there is a total of 5 upvotes now - see the reputation) and have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @pippo1980 Oh, I assumed you were replying to a comment. As it stands it looks like you're asking quamrana why they're bashing the OP in their comment immediately above yours when they aren't doing that. FWIW I also upvoted and voted to reopen.

Comment: Code in source files is executed *in-order*. Something written later cannot happen before something written earlier (and vice versa).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
integer_number = int(input("something here"))
```

is the equivalent*** of saying:

```
temp_var = input("something here")
integer_number = int(temp_var)
```

It is not the other way around, because the `int()` function takes a string and converts it into an `int`. If you did it the other way around, the function wouldn't have anything to convert.

*** : In Python functions are first-class objects. You can assign them to variables, store them in data structures, pass them as arguments to other functions, and even return them as values from other functions. So there is no need to create `temp_var` with `input("something here)"`and pass it as an argument to `int` using `int(temp_var)` You can just use them directly like in : `int(input("something here"))`

Comment: I dont think this is correct : Python's functions are first-class objects. You can assign them to variables, store them in data structures, pass them as arguments to other functions, and even return them as values from other functions., temp_var does not exist in the OP question

Comment: I know temp var isn't in the original, somebody edited the question.

Comment: I edited the code here to make it clear that `integer_number` is only assigned to at the end. Actually python uses its stack to store `temp_var` and not a named variable.

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can pass functions as arguments of another function and of course they'll be evaluated before the outer function. Guess I should point you to the relevant official Python documentation that states that, but just googling for it isn't working right now.

See [Python’s Functions Are First-Class](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions):

> Python's functions are first-class objects. You can assign them to variables, store them in data structures, pass them as arguments to other functions, and even return them as values from other functions.

Got a nice answer about that on SO :

[What are "first-class" objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245208/9877065):

> In short, it means there are no restrictions on the object's use.   It's the same as any other object.

> A first class object is an entity that can be dynamically created, destroyed, passed to a function, returned as a value, and have all the rights as other variables in the programming language have.

Your one is not the first question about that:

[All arguments are evaluated before the function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563576/all-arguments-are-evaluated-before-the-function-is-called):

Answer:

> You are right, all arguments are evaluated before the function is called, otherwise the function cannot know what is passed to it. So what you are doing is actually:

but no link to docs here too.

Took a while, I found it here:

[6.3.4. Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) its the link for Python 3:

> ...............All argument expressions are evaluated before the call is attempted. Please refer to section Function definitions for the syntax of formal parameter lists.........

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input("something")`, it asks the user for input, and `return`s a *string*, here `"something"` is an *argument* to `input()`

Calling `int()` on that *output* attempts to convert it to an `int`, the input here (whatever the user input) is the *argument* to `int()`

If you had `input(int("something"))`, what happens is `"something"` is passed to `int()`, raising an Exception (because that literal string can't be a valid `int`)

Answer (score 1):

To begin, the code begins by utilizing the `input()` function to request an integer from the user. The prompt `"Enter an integer: "` is shown, clearly indicating the desired type of input. Next, the input is converted into an integer using the `int()` function. This important step guarantees that the value entered by the user is treated as a whole number, making it suitable for mathematical calculations and avoiding any possible errors. The variable `integer_number` is then assigned the converted integer, containing the final result of the code.

Next, we invoke the useful `print()` function to deliver a customized message alongside the integer that was entered. The message `"You entered:"` is smoothly followed by the integer value stored in the variable `integer_number`, giving the user reassurance of their input.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you put int before input is because input automatically sets whatever you typed in as a string. Then the int function kicks in and sets whatever to a integer. Had you done it the other way, you would have set it to an integer and then a string as well as have an error because input must have something like this:

```
i = input('print things here')
```

with quotation marks to indicate what you print and then ask for input. With input(int('input')) it would try and print int('input') without quotations around it and would cause it to have an error.